# Visual Studio Universal App Resource is not found when in Shared folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

This problem is mainly bother some as Visual Studio IDE is telling me that it cant find the resource, but when I build the application I am not having any problem.

In my Visual Studio i have this:
 [image]

Here is an example of my Universal App architecture  is as Follows:

Example.windowsPhone

```
->MainPage.xaml
```

Example.Share

```
-> Style.xaml
-> App.Xaml has Style.xaml referenced
```

Eventhought i have reference DmBlueBrush in my Style Page like this :

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DmBlueBrush" Color="{StaticResource DmBlue}" />
```

In Visual Studio it will tell me that it cant find it, but when I build the application it will find this resource.  Have I not reference something correctly for my IDE to work?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4.

Edit 1:

in App.xaml in Shared i Have:

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/Styles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/Other.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you need to merge the ResourceDictionary directly from inside the other ResourceDictionary, instead of including them both in App.xaml.

See here for a complete example:
http://blog.craftingbytes.com/2015/05/resource-sharing-in-windows-universal.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you link your Resource Dictionary?

> Right click Shared Project > Add > New Item > Resource Dictionary

For this example, named it MyStyles.xaml

Then in App.xaml link by

```XAML
<Application
    x:Class="YOUR_CLASS.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:YOUR_CLASS">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyStyles.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

---

example MyStyles.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:YOUR_CLASS">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyGreen" Color="Green"/>    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Yes the style xaml file is referenced in the App.xaml file that is located in the shared folder

Comment: @Damien hmm, your best bet is then do a clean solution -> rebuild.  I created a blank universal project / two style files and was able to reference any `x:Key` I wanted as a Static Resource.  Try with a blank universal project and see if that helps.  If so, then figure out what is different from a default blank vs your project.